# Verifying downloaded images

Tags: android, network-programming, threadpool

I am downloading images from a server with the help of a Thread Pool. If an image fails to download, say because the local network connection is lost, or the server goes off-line, what methods can I used to check the download is complete and the image is valid? Currently I don't know it is corrupt until I am accessing the file.

Comment: Did you try putting in some kind of exception handling logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapFactory methods will return a Bitmap when successful, or null if the bitmap could not be decoded.